# Laravel Eloquent sub sub table query

Tags: eloquent, eager-loading

So I have a `persons` table.

Then I have another table `jobs` which is linked to Persons with foreign key.

I also have another table `jobs_photos` which is linked to the `jobs` table.

Now I can get a person and job by the person's `id`.

```
Return Person::with('person.job')->find ($person_id);
```

Which will return object of person and job.

Now how do I also get the jobs_photos? because jobs_photos didn't store person_id, so I can't use $person_id as parameter?

Answer (score 0):

You could include another level to load photos related to jobs like

```
Person::with('job.photos')->find($person_id);
```

I assume your `Job` model has mapping defined for photos as `hasMany`